# Nuget Visual Studio 2022 control dependency version

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2022

Whenever I try to install any package from Nuget through Visual Studio 2022 - be it the GUI or package manager console, I can't seem to find a way to get the highest dependency version.

For example: if I add latest version 1.0.152 `protobuf-net.Grpc` to my project it has a dependency on `Grpc.Core.Api >= 2.36.1`. The current version for `Grpc.Core.Api` is 2.46.3...

In the GUI under options I have no option to control dependency version what so ever it seems like the `Install-Package` cmdlet doesn't obey `-DependencyVersion Highest`:

```
Install-Package protobuf-net.Grpc -DependencyVersion Highest

Installing NuGet package protobuf-net.Grpc 1.0.152.
Committing restore...
Successfully installed 'Grpc.Core.Api 2.36.1'
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 2.1.0'
Successfully installed 'protobuf-net 2.4.6'
Successfully installed 'protobuf-net.Grpc 1.0.152'
Successfully installed 'System.Memory 4.5.3'
Successfully installed 'System.Private.ServiceModel 4.5.3'
Successfully installed 'System.Reflection.DispatchProxy 4.5.0'
Successfully installed 'System.Security.Principal.Windows 4.5.0'
Successfully installed 'System.ServiceModel.Primitives 4.5.3'
```

How can I force Nuget to install the highest dependencies version?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description here are some suggestion:

First check your project type “-DependencyVersion Highest” only [used in packages.config format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section).

You can see the [project type support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#project-type-support) about two package management formats: Projects.config and PackageReference.

Someone posted a similar issue on github, see the issue [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8327). Hope this help you.

If you want to use “Grpc.Core.Api 2.46.3 “, you can try to delete the bin and obj folder and then go to Tools>Options>Nuget Package Manager>General>Clear All Nuget Caches.

Then you can install Grpc.Core.Api 2.46.3 package before install protobuf-net.Grpc 1.0.152

Comment: My project is based on .NET 6 and from what I read there's no support for packages.config on .NET 6 projects?

Comment: .net 6.0 uses PackageReference by default. And there is no documentation telling us how to migrate from PackageReference to packages.config

Comment: Meaning... can't be done? Or can't be done officially? :D

Comment: You can try to switch back to packages.config according to this method (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45964469/17296043 )